# CANNOT find SSH Target in remote explorer (vscode)

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

vscode version：(version 1.82)
installed extensions：
Remote - SSH v0.106.4
Remote - SSH: Editing Configuration Files v0.86.0
Remote Development v0.24.0
WSL v0.81.3

I want to connect to the Linux server by SSH. But after I installed the extensions above, SSH target were still not found in the remote explorer. There were only Dev Containers and WSL Target. I have successfully connected the server by SSH in pycharm. How to solve this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFx5r.png)

I searched online and found some advices about changing the version of extension, but useless. I also found that maybe I should install Remote Containers, but I can't find it in the extensions store.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It is no necessery to find the "SSH taget", just using the remote SSH tunnel to connected to the server. If "the tunnel isn't existed", you can use"icacls "key address" /grant:r 11094:"(R)"" in cmd.

Answer (score 2):

I just found it need to install "Remote Explorer" extension to show the ssh target list in remote explorer.
[Remote Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.remote-explorer)